# bottleneck tries to install numpy release candidate

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pip

due to legacy reasons I have to use python2 (that mentioned first to keep in mind).

Bottleneck specifies in it's `setup.py` to require `numpy`. If installed from the same requirements file (even if pinned numpy to a proper version), it tries to install the `numpy==1.17.0rc` release candidate, which drops support for python2 and therefore the following error occurs:

```
[stderr] File "/tmp/easy_install-8dcHVX/numpy-1.17.0rc1/setup.py", line 31, in <module>
[stderr] from bottleneck.src.template import make_c_files
[stderr] RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.5 required.
[stderr] ----------------------------------------
[stderr]ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-hhfr2i/bottleneck/
```

I'm seeking for an option to solve this. Temporarly solved by installing numpy first manually, but that's building around the requirements and not intended.

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: any luck resolving this?

Comment: no, got rid of python2 actually

Answer (score 0):

It showed, that the deployment was partially broken, therefore the proper `requirements.txt` wasn't used for installing packages.

Having `numpy` listed before `bottleneck` solves this, e.g.

```
numpy==1.16.4
...
bottleneck
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me. it bums out `16:34:57 exec(code, globals, locals)
16:34:57 File "/tmp/easy_install-pH6Ptb/numpy-1.17.1/setup.py", line 31, in <module>
16:34:57 from bottleneck.src.template import make_c_files
16:34:57 RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.5 required.`

Comment: it works when creating a new virtualenv with py2.7 and requirements e.g. this: `numpy==1.16.4, pandas==0.20.3, pandas_profiling==1.4.1, pandas_gbq, bottleneck` - can you verify you did this steps (`virtualenv new_env`, source this, `pip install -r requirements.txt` with above requirements in that order)?

Comment: yup. my log shows numpy 1 16 4 being installed prior to bottleneck. and the virtual env is fresh py2.7

Comment: sounds weird, thought i catched every error. from my perspective you should open a new question with further details on what you do and what output occurs

Comment: it turns out an older version of fabric was the culprit. updating fabric solved the issue.