# How to install pip packages via --no-build-isolation when they are mentioned in requirements.txt?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

Context :
This is the problem https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6717#issue-468204416 I'm facing
and trying to solve via
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6717#issuecomment-511652167

I want to use

```
--no-build-isolation
```

In a py2.7 venv If I do:

```
pip install bottleneck==1.2.1 --no-build-isolation

Collecting bottleneck==1.2.1
Collecting numpy (from bottleneck==1.2.1)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d7/b1/3367ea1f372957f97a6752ec725b87886e12af1415216feec9067e31df70/numpy-1.16.5-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (17.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 17.0MB 1.2MB/s 
Installing collected packages: numpy, bottleneck
Successfully installed bottleneck-1.2.1 numpy-1.16.5
You are using pip version 18.0, however version 19.2.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

It installs fine

```
$ cat abc.txt 
bottleneck==1.2.1, --no-build-isolation
```

but

```
$pip install -r abc.txt
Usage: pip [options]

Invalid requirement: bottleneck==1.2.1, --no-build-isolation
pip: error: no such option: --no-build-isolation

You are using pip version 18.0, however version 19.2.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

and

```
$ pip install -r abc.txt
Usage: pip [options]

Invalid requirement: bottleneck==1.2.1 --no-build-isolation
pip: error: no such option: --no-build-isolation

You are using pip version 18.0, however version 19.2.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

don't work.

How do I go about it.

I also tried [bottleneck tries to install numpy release candidate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56931824/bottleneck-tries-to-install-numpy-release-candidate) but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading pip to pip-20.2.2 solved this proplem for me.
command

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Not working for me:
```
Seans-MacBook-Pro:connectors-python seanstory$ bin/pip3 --version
pip 23.2 from /Users/seanstory/Desktop/Dev/connectors-python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)
Seans-MacBook-Pro:connectors-python seanstory$ bin/pip3 install -r requirements/tests.txt 
Usage: pip3 [options]

ERROR: Invalid requirement: memray==1.8.1, --no-build-isolation
pip3: error: no such option: --no-build-isolation
```

Comment: Looks like pip no longer supports this option. See: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/requirements-file-format/#supported-options

Answer (score 0):

These days (pip 23) `--no-build-isolation` is not listed as one of the supported options in a `requirements.txt` file. See: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/requirements-file-format/#supported-options